# Component-preload.js not beeing created

Tags: gruntjs, sapui5

I'm trying to generate a Component-preload.js file fy SAPUi5 application. I'm using the grunt-openui5 plugin.

I'm able to generate the Component-preload.js if i set the compress paramter of the options to false. If i set the parameter to true noch Component-prelaod.js file is generated. 
What can be the reason? I want the Component-preload.js to be minified.
Here the snipplet from my Gruntfile.js i'm using.

```
openui5_preload: {
webapp: {
options: {
resources: {
                    cwd: '<%= webapp.srcRoot %>', // this should point to the entry folder
                    prefix: '<%= webapp.prefix %>', // this should be your component namespace
                    src: [
                        "!Component-preload.js",
                        "**/*.js",
                        "**/*.xml",
                        "*/*.js",
                        "*/*.xml",
                        "*.js",
                        "*.xml",
                        "**/*.properties",
                        "model/*.json",
                        "*.json",
                        "*.js",
                        "**/*.css",
                        "!Gruntfile.js"
                    ],
                },

                // "dest" needs to be defined within "options" not "options.resources"
                dest: "<%= webapp.targetRoot %>", // to put the file in the same folder
                compress: true
            },
            components: true
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had some corrupted JavaScript files in my path which prevents the compress task to create the file. 
Unfortunately the grunt-openui5 plugin in version 0.7.0 does not show any error message for that. I used the version 0.11.0 of the plugin and then i found the file causing problems.